# Ffmpeg makes audio longer when changing bitrate

Tags: ffmpeg, aac

I've been using ffmpeg convert audio from one format to another and to change audio's bitrate. When I try to convert aac audio to mp3 audio using the command:

**ffmpeg -i SomeAudio.aac -c:a mp3 -b:a 128k SomeOutputPath.mp3**

everything works correctly and output audio is of the same length as the input audio (6 minutes, 15 seconds).

However, when I try converting it to aac audio using a similar command:

**ffmpeg -i SomeAudio.aac -c:a aac -b:a 128k SomeOutputPath.aac**

it makes the output audio longer (around 10 minutes). I have tried specifying output length but that still makes the video longer, it just cuts of part of the audio:

**ffmpeg -i SomeAudio.aac -c:a aac -b:a 128k -t 00:06:15 SomeOutputPath.aac**

Here is a link to the screenshot:

[image: Changing aac bitrate]

My suspicion is that message "Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be innacurate" (the one in the screenshot) is the root of my problem but I just haven't been able to find any useful information about it on the web.

Thanks a lot for any help in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The duration shown for raw AAC is a guess because it does not contain duration info. You can find the actual duration with:

```
ffmpeg -i input.aac -f null -
```

Or a faster, "close enough" method:

```
ffmpeg -i input.aac -c copy -f null -
```

Workaround is to remux to M4A:

```
ffmpeg -i input.aac -c copy output.m4a
```

Comment: It does convert it to the specified bitrate when I specify -b:a in the third command you posted and the audio is of the right length. The only problem is that when I convert it to aac extension the duration is wrong, which I don't understand why because I am just copying the audio stream from m4a file to aac file and the audio in m4a file is in aac format (-i input.m4a -c:a copy output.aac). So this workaround is really good, but it would be amazing if m4a could then be converted to aac without the duration problem. Thanks so much again! :))

Comment: @ReflexLevel0 It doesn't matter if you go from `.aac` → `.m4a` → `.aac`. The problem is that `.aac` is not ever guaranteed to have an accurate duration. By "workaround" I meant that you should use `.m4a` instead of `.aac` if you need an accurate duration. Sorry, should have been more clear about that.